# No JaCoCo execution data dumped / classloader problems

Tags: macos, maven, sonarqube, jacoco

I'm trying to analyse the jajuk source code with sonarqube for a research paper.
I've got everything working, except for the code coverage and unit tests.
I seem to have a problem with jacoco not dumping the report info.
Since I'm on Mac, I'm running sonarqube 3.7.4. If I update to the java 2.0 plugin (now on 1.3) in order to use cobertura for code coverage, sonarqube stops working completely...
Could this be caused by a lot of classes not loading with the classloader?
The source code does not compile correctly by the way, actually the build succeeds when using 
    mvn jar:jar
but the jar file cannot be run  (main class not found).

It should be such an easy thing, but I just can't get my head around what's going wrong here. I just want to analyse some source code for my paper :(

Comment: Have you seen this example project? https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/projects/languages/java/code-coverage/ut/ut-maven-jacoco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the "*source code does not compile correctly*", then no wonder why you can't get JaCoCo results. Fix this issue first and everything should be OK.